# Transposing Rows in Openrefine

Tags: pivot, transpose, openrefine

I am using Openrefine (openrefine-2.6-rc.2) running on Windows and opening with Chrome browser (65.033225.181

I have data in text format (.txt) that I have imported into Openrefine for cleaning and processing.   The data entries reside in rows under one column.  I would like to "transpose" (pivot) the items in the rows so they appear in columns

Following is an example of the current state:

```
Column 1

Mary Smith
Company Name IBM
Location New York

John Davis
Company Name Lockheed-Martin
Location Los Angeles

Jane Segal
Company Name Microsoft
Location Boston
```

Ideally, by transposing the entries the result would look like this:

```
Last Name   First Name  Company Name    Location
Smith       Mary         IBM            New York
Davis       John         Lockheed       Los Angeles
Segal       Jane         Microsoft      Boston
```

Just not sure how to do this in Openrefine

Answer (score 1):

When creating your Open Refine project, make sure that empty rows are not imported.

[image]

You can delete them later, but it's a little more complicated (see screencast).

Then, just :

1° Apply the function `Transpose -> Transpose cells in rows into columns`, with a value of 3.

2° Delete the words "Company Name" and "Location" using a Transform with formulas like `value.replace('Company Name', '').trim()` and `value.replace('Location', '').trim()`

3° Rename the columns.

Here is a visual tutorial.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. This is a very clear and efficient solution  In practice,  a number of the entries have more than 3 rows associated with them.  So to use the technique proposed, I need to find a way to standardize the lengths. Perhaps, by padding cells. Will experiment with this.

Comment: @PaulRoss You're welcome. Feel free to ask another question with a more realistic dataset example and to accept this answer if it's right.

Comment: Thank you for the kind offer.  Maybe I'll experiment a bit myself first and see how far I get.  I find I learn a lot in the process of doing that and then with any luck I'll be able to help other people out down the road.